# Chrome extension - onclick icon event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

As you can see, I have a problem with onclick event in chrome extension and I need your help.

```
$(function jony() {
    jQuery.each( jQuery('img'), function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', 'urlimage');
    });
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   jony();
});
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Jonyzátor",
  "description": "Change images on page to JoNy!",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Klikni na mě!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "jonyza.js"],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're having? It's not visible at all... What kind of help do you need? There's no question you ask.

Comment: Well, when I click on then icon, I want the script to run. The problem I have right now is that it loads automatically on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The scope in which `jony` is defined is limited to `$()`; outside it's simply undefined.

   ```
   function jony() {
     jQuery.each( jQuery('img'), function() {
     jQuery(this).attr('src', 'urlimage');
   }

   $(jony); // Will execute on page load

   // and you can still use it here
   ```

   I'm not sure it was the logic you intended - do you want it to run both at page load AND when you click?
2. You can't use `browserAction` API in content scripts. The proper place for it would be a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (or [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) script, and then you can [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) your content script to do something.

Comment: I want it only to do the script when I click on the icon.

Comment: @AlešŠvec Then you don't need to call it within a [ready listener](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).